# Can I double a single spell attack's range multiple times by taking multiple versions of the Spell Sniper feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, ranged-attack, stacking

I was looking at the *Player's Handbook* and I saw that there are 3 different types for Spell Sniper.

Simply put, does choosing all three of them create an 8 times multiplier?

For example, say that a Level 10 Arcane Trickster rogue were to use the three Ability Score Improvements they had to take three feats instead.

The feats taken (in no particular order) are Spell Sniper (Bard, Sorcerer, Warlock), Spell Sniper (Cleric, Druid), and Spell Sniper (Wizard).

Does the range benefit of each version of the feat stack, multiplying the range of any spell that requires an attack roll by a total of 8?

(I just inputted the values on D&D Beyond, and it seem like they added the multipliers together for 6 times multiplier. Fire Bolt has a range of 720 ft and Thorn Whip has a range of 180 ft. This is increased from 120 ft and 30 ft. Is this correct on their part?)

Comment: Related on [Can you take the same feat multiple times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60025/can-you-take-the-same-feat-multiple-times)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Multiple Spell Sniper Feats is an artifact of dndbeyond

In the PHB (170), the Spell Sniper feat is a single feat. At the end of the description it states:

> Choose the cantrip from the bard, cleric, druid, sorceror, warlock, or wizard spell list. Your spellcasting ability for this depends on the spell list you choose from: Charisma for bard, sorceror or warlock; Wisdom for cleric or druid; or Intelligence for wizard.

The three "separate" feats are those separated by the spellcasting ability so that it fits neatly into their character creation tool. It's not actually three separate feats, but a single feat and you need to choose the applicable one for your class and spellcasting ability.

Even if it was three, you'd still fall under the issue of [not being able to take the same feat multiple times](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60025/can-you-take-the-same-feat-multiple-times).

Comment: Well, that's too bad. I wanted to make a warlock with all 3 and Eldritch Spear to have Eldritch Blast with a range of 1800 ft :D

Comment: @aCit EVen if you did, you'd need to pick which spellcasting modifier you were using. I mean, I guess you could do the 1800ft, but would have to pick the modifier. And I don't think i've ever been at a table where anything beyond 120 or so was even possible.

Comment: You can get it to 600 with just the Spell Sniper feat and the Eldritch Spear invocation

Comment: @aCit I didn't say that it can't be more. I'm saying that realistically at a table, I've never seen an opportunity to do it more than that. But that's purely my experience only, your tables may be different (and probably are!)

Comment: Yeah, *Eldritch Spear* + *Spell Sniper* falls under the umbrella of *Cool, but Inefficient* The situations where you need more than a 200' range on a target is exceedingly rare, and needing a 600' range is virtually non-existent. Not to mention the difficulty of even *spotting* something that far away :p

Comment: @RevenantBacon How about we add Distant Spell Metamagic to the mix? :D

Comment: @aCit and throw in the lore wizard's 2nd level alchemical casting. A 3 mile range isn't anything to scoff at.

Comment: @RevenantBacon, 600' range IRL isn't even long range combat, and is easily in te realm of open sight rifles.  It jut doesn't fit well on a tabletop 1" grid.