# Do different versions of the same feat stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, stacking

The reason I ask this is because there are several different versions of the Spell Sniper feat, and all of them double range for ranged spells with attack rolls. Most feats that are like this specify they don’t stack, but not Spell Sniper.  I'm not asking how you'd rule it, I'm asking if the base rules allow it. I can't find anything on this. I'm hopeful because this would mean that a sorcerer + warlock could eventually have a range of 9600 feet with *eldritch blast*.

Answer (score 7):

#### You can take each feat only once, unless stated otherwise.

Per the rules for [feats](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Feats) on PHB page 165:

> You can take each feat only once, unless the feat’s description says otherwise.

An example of a feat that can be taken more than once (and the sole official example so far) is [Elemental Adept](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/elemental-adept) (PHB, p. 166).

There is only one [Spell Sniper](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/spell-sniper) feat (PHB, p. 170), and it doesn't say you can take it multiple times - so you can't. A sorcerer using the [Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option Distant Spell could be used to double the spell's range on top of the benefits of the Spell Sniper feat, since that's not taking a feat more than once, just a similar effect from a class feature.

Comment: As far as I can tell, [that's the only feat that can be taken more than once](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/132499/22566).